# ImportError: No module named resample

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a python script which is running on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (LTS (Xenial Xerus), pandas version 0.20 and python 2.7, which gives the error message:

```
from pandas.tseries.resample import TimeGrouper 
ImportError: No module named resample
```

Can't find any other error in the logs or any other information. This script used to work before, but I also could not find any changes in the python official docs.

Any help?

Comment: Have you try install the missing package with `pip install resample` or `sudo pip install resample`?

Comment: of course yes! `No matching distribution found for resample` is what it said ;) I am wondering whats the correct package that is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the import as in pandas 0.20 it was changed to a different module

use the import as

```
from pandas.core.resample import TimeGrouper
```